# renv::restore() failing to restore library installing Matrix: compilation failed

Tags: r, macos, gfortran, renv

I use renv to snapshot the package library I need for a data set I created: https://github.com/mtwente/nordatlantisk-ft. However, I cloned the repository on another computer and wanted to restore the project library using `renv::restore()` which lead to a large chunk of error messages.

The computer on which renv throws the error has the folloing `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.2.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2 tools_4.3.2    renv_1.0.3
```

I opened the project in R Studio and ran `renv::restore()`. renv downloaded the packages as recorded the lockfile:

```
> renv::restore()
The following package(s) will be updated:

# CRAN -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Since the post is too long, I put the list of installed packages here: [https://pastebin.com/QyjF9311](https://pastebin.com/QyjF9311)

Do you want to proceed? [Y/n]: y
```

Yes, I do.

```
# Downloading packages -------------------------------------------------------
- Downloading Matrix from CRAN ...              OK [file is up to date]
- Downloading mgcv from CRAN ...                OK [file is up to date]

# R telling me that it successfully downloaded the other packages mentioned above...

Successfully downloaded 111 packages in 240 seconds.
```

This seems to have worked just fine, but then...

```
# Installing packages --------------------------------------------------------
- Installing lattice ...                        OK [linked from cache]
- Installing Matrix ...
```

I get this wall of red lines. I cannot even scroll back to the very top in R Studio, because it is such a long output.

```
                              ^
../Core/t_cholmod_transpose.c:44:21: warning: variable 'nrow' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    Int j, p, pend, nrow, ncol, Apacked, use_fset, fp, Fpacked, jj, permute ;
                    ^
../Core/t_cholmod_transpose.c:44:56: warning: variable 'Fpacked' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    Int j, p, pend, nrow, ncol, Apacked, use_fset, fp, Fpacked, jj, permute ;

# Since the post is too long, I put the most part of the error messages here: [https://pastebin.com/EEVzNRf5](https://pastebin.com/EEVzNRf5)

ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'gfortran' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
* removing ‘/Users/[username]/github/nordatlantisk-ft/renv/staging/1/Matrix’
install of package 'Matrix' failed [error code 1]
```

I don't even understand the error mesage in the first place, but this is very confusing to me due to the fact that renv worked just fine on the computer on which I set up the project.

There, I just get:

```
> renv::status()
No issues found -- the project is in a consistent state.
```

What was I expecting? I expected `renv::restore()` to install the packages recorded in my lockfile so I could use the scripts regardless of what computer I am using at the moment.

Any help to understand this errors is appreciated and also any help on how to resolve this so I can use renv as it is supposed to work!

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the system of your new computer is running OSX. On new OSX systems you need a Fortran compiler for the `Matrix` library (Fortran is one of the compiled programming languages R utilises for package development etc.). Have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/) and [here](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/). Quoting the first link:
"In short, you need at the very least Xcode and a Fortran compiler. R 4.3.0 and higher use universal GNU Fortran 12.2 compiler."

You will find the download links for on the pages that I shared.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasK81, I did not realise this was the only issue given all the extra error output. I manually installed the Fortran compiler and now it works just fine.

Comment: Small correction: you need the Fortran compiler on *every* platform on which you want to compile the ‘Matrix’ package, not just on macOS. On Windows it’s included with Rtools and on Linux it is often (though not always) already installed via a meta-package such as ‘build-essential’.