# library 'gfortran' not found when installing R packages

Tags: r, c, gfortran

I am installing an R package that relies on gfortran.

As below, I get such errors.

```
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'gfortran' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, I have gcc and gfortran installed.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ which gfortran
/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran
```

I also have Xcode downloaded from app store and run `xcode-select –-install already`.

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran` is the compiler, not the library.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65180133/1216776

Comment: [https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/) provides `gfortran-6.1.pkg`.

Comment: now that ld: library 'emutls_w' not found comes up...

Comment: If gfortran is the compiler, why is R saying that library 'gfortran' not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Till pointed out, I'd install fortran from the macosx [r-project space](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/). It seems like a path variable is not set properly on your system. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77822707/renvrestore-failing-to-restore-library-installing-matrix-compilation-failed/77823134#comment137199912_77823134).

If you really want to use the homebrew version of fortran for the use in R make sure that RStudio uses the right path variable. You could follow this [guide](https://www.cynkra.com/blog/2021-03-16-gfortran-macos/). However installing gfortran-12.2-universal.pkg from the link above is a lot less of a pain.